# PInvoke Calling C++ code in C# - ObjectPinning

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to follow tutorial calling code from C++ into C#.

I followed the coding part correctly.

But when I run the code I get exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'SampleNativeLib': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

I create C# library as simple application file.
And C++ as dynamic .dll.

In the original tutorial (I also have full project file of it) in the C# project in the references there are no references to C++ .dll.
I would like to ask how C++ is referenced to C#?

The code of C#

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ObjectPinning {
    class Program {

        [DllImport("SampleNativeLib")]
        static extern int SetData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] darray);

        [DllImport("SampleNativeLib")]
        static extern int DoCalc();

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => i + 1).ToArray();
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            Console.WriteLine(SetData(data));
            Console.WriteLine(DoCalc());
            Console.ReadLine();
            GC.Collect();//Clean up any garbage object
            Console.WriteLine(DoCalc());
            handle.Free();

        }
    }
}
```

The code of C++:

```
// SampleNativeLib.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

int* g_pData;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI DoCalc() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        sum += g_pData[i];
    return sum;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI SetData(int* data) {
    g_pData = data;
    return DoCalc();
}
```

My project file:
[Download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnwaB50XU22eipxpl-j9YfOERnr1Jg)

Teachers File:
[Download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnwaB50XU22eipxoY1H2-JMgH9tGrQ)

My file
[image]

Teacher File
[image]

Comment: Is SampleNativeLib.dll in the same directory as the output from your c# code? The C++ project needs to be built and the DLL placed where the C# code can find it.

Comment: I always prefer to import my C++ code to CLI then I can use it in any .NET programming language

Comment: Besides putting the file in the same directory, you are missing .dll in the imported name

Comment: I just tried to copy SampleNativeLib.dl to C#  app build directory. But still I get the same error. @DrYunke What do you mean "You are missing .dll in the imported name" ?

Comment: [DllImport("SampleNativeLib.dll")] instead of  [DllImport("SampleNativeLib")]

Comment: Oh, I had different builds, 64 and 32 bits. And I was copying SampleNativeLib.dll - not the right one to C# app directory. Now It works... I still do not get why I did not need to reference it in C# project just to copy .dll file. C++ and C# interoperability is really confusing for me... Thank you  Ron Beyer and Dr Yunke it helped. By the way, maybe you know good tutorials regarding interoperability between C++ and C#?

Comment: Native libraries are completely different to assemblies. When you reference an assembly in C# (or any .net language) the IDE loads all the metadata about the code in the assembly and incorporates this info into the project, and when you compile the project the compiler uses also this metadata to create the calls and references. C++ does not work this way, metadata is external, header files, but these files aren't usable by .net and that's why you need to declare a dllImport, so basically you don't need the reference because you're manually declaring the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get is most likely because you didn't add the dll to the C# executable path. In the first step the application searching the dependencies in the exe directory, if not found, then it goes through the Window environment variables. That is why we don't need to copy the dlls when we use some of the Windows API function, because if you look at at your PATH variable, you'll have %SystemRoot% variable which links to your windows folder.
In C# you can't really reference C++ projects as you already know when adding another C# project, since you calling from managed code to unmanaged/native code.
Important note when you building your own C++ dll, make sure the compiler environment set to x32 bit, otherwise you'll get some other exceptions when calling C++ code from C#. 
What actually expose the C++ function to allow for it consumed by other languages, is the:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

On the signature of the function. So that gives you the power to do almost everything you can do with C++ also in C#/Java.